# How can we debug and log API call in React Server Component, e.g. Next.js appDir

Tags: node.js, reactjs, debugging, next.js

## Background

As we all know about Next.js pagesDir, we can debug easily API call in browser or pass it using node inspector to out dev terminal. But, it's not the case in Next.js appDir.

## Problem

I can't figure out what's the way recommended for me to debug a React Server Component API call that has been called in the server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Current Solution

I'm using normal `console.log` at this time for debugging. I'm currently not using node debugger as usual when I'm using Next.js pagesDir.

It's pretty convenient too and enough for my requirements.

For production deployment, relying on a logging service with a session replay feature is very helpful to troubleshoot the problem the user facing.